# Swift, is it possible to #if on a C macro

Tags: swift

As titled, I have

`#define VK_VERSION_1_0`

in the [header](https://github.com/swift-graphics/glfw/blob/master/Sources/glfwNative/glfw.h#L1) importing the glfw header

I'd like to use exactly that in [my code](https://github.com/swift-graphics/glfw/blob/master/Sources/glfw_/glfw.swift#L2054) before functions that use Vulkan identifiers (such as `VkInstance` in `glfwGetPhysicalDevicePresentationSupport`), that is

```
#if VK_VERSION_1_0
    func getPhysicalDevicePresentationSupport(instance: VkInstance, device: VkPhysicalDevice, queuefamily: Int) -> Bool {
        glfwGetPhysicalDevicePresentationSuppsort(instance, device, UInt32(queuefamily)) == GLFW_TRUE
    }
#endif
```

but this doesn't work. I know I may pass `-D VK_VERSION_1_0` to the compiler, but I'd like to rely on one unique variable/flag..

is it possible somehow to reference the `VK_VERSION_1_0` declared in the header (as `#define VK_VERSION_1_0`)?